# Want to clarify whether I am correct or not, $\Phi(G) \subseteq \Phi(H)$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I Want you to clarify whether I am correct or not regarding following question. I will be thankful to you for telling me if I am wrong:

Let $G$ be finite group and $\Phi(G)$ denotes its frattini subgroup. Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ such that $\Phi(G) \subseteq H$. Since $\Phi(G)$ is group of all non generators of $G$ therefore it also non generators for $H$. This implies that $\Phi(G) \subseteq \Phi(H)$.

regards

Steve

Answer (score 3):

No. Take $G$ to be the dihedral group of order $8$. The Frattini subgroup is the unique normal subgroup of order $2$. But $G$ has two subgroups of order $4$ that are elementary abelian (and as such, they have trivial Frattini subgroup) and yet they contain $\Phi(G)$.

Comment: My favorite group,  dihedral 8, is working here for you! Good job it has. :D and +1

Answer (score 3):

It does not work. The hole is in the statement $x$ is a non-generator of $G$ implies $x$ is non-generator of $H$. For an example illustrating why the claim is false,  suppose $\Phi(G)$ is nontrivial and $H=\Phi(G)$.